# When using std::move with a lambda when does the move happen

Tags: c++, std

If I create a lambda in a function and capture a variable to the lambda using std::move, when does the move happen? Is it when the lambda is created or when the lambda is executed?

Take the following code for example ... when do the various moves happen? Is it thread safe if myFunction is called on one thread and testLambda is executed on another thread?

```
class MyClass {
private:
  // Only accessed on thread B
  std::vector<int> myStuff;

  // Called from thread A with new data
  void myFunction(const std::vector<int>&& theirStuff) {

    // Stored to be called on thread B 
    auto testLambda = [this, _theirStuff{ std::move(theirStuff) }]() { 
      myStuff = std::move(_theirStuff);
    };

    // ... store lambda
}

// Elsewhere on thread A
void someOtherFunction() {
  std::vector<int> newStuff = { 1, 2, .... n };
  gGlobalMyClass->myFunction(std::move(newStuff));
}
```

Comment: Remember that `std::move` is nothing but a *cast*. It does not itself actually move *anything*.

Comment: afaik, `const T&&` means it won't be moved at all

Answer (score 1):

> If I create a lambda in a function and capture a variable to the lambda using std::move, when does the move happen? Is it when the lambda is created or when the lambda is executed?

If you had written what I believe you intended to write, then the answer would be: both. Currently, the answer is: neither. You have a lambda capture `_theirStuff { std::move(theirStuff) }`. This basically declares a member of the closure type, which will be initialized when the closure object is created as if it were

```
auto _theirStuff { std::move(theirStuff) };
```

You also have

```
myStuff = std::move(_theirStuff);
```

in the lambda body.

However, your parameter `theirStuff` is actually an rvalue reference to a `const std::vector<int>`. Thus, `_theirStuff { std::move(theirStuff) }` is not actually going to perform a move, because a `const std::vector` cannot be moved from. Most likely, you wanted to write `std::vector<int>&& theirStuff` instead. Furthermore, as pointed out by @JVApen in the comments below, your lambda is not mutable. Therefore, `_theirStuff` will actually be const as well, and, thus, also cannot be moved from. Consequently, your code above, despite all the `std::move`, will actually make a copy of the vector every time. If you had written

```
void myFunction(std::vector<int>&& theirStuff)
{
    auto testLambda = [this, _theirStuff { std::move(theirStuff) }]() { 
        myStuff = std::move(_theirStuff);
    };
}
```

You would be moving `theirStuff` into `_theirStuff` when the closure object is created. And you would be copying `_theirStuff` into `myStuff` when the lambda is called. If you had written

```
void myFunction(std::vector<int>&& theirStuff)
{
    auto testLambda = [this, _theirStuff { std::move(theirStuff) }]() mutable { 
        myStuff = std::move(_theirStuff);
    };
}
```

Then you would be moving `theirStuff` into `_theirStuff` when the closure object is created. And you would be moving `_theirStuff` into `myStuff` when the lambda is called. Note that, as a consequence, your lambda then cannot really be called twice. I mean, it can, but it will only really work once since `_theirStuff` will be empty after the first time the lambda is called…

Also, note that above description is only valid for the particular combination of types in your example. There is no general definition of what it actually means to move an object. What it means to move an object is entirely up to the particular type of the object. It may not even mean anything. `std::move` itself does not really do anything. All it does is cast the given expression to an rvalue reference. If you then initialize another object from the result of `std::move`, or assign the result to an object, overload resolution will pick a move constructor or move assignment operator—if one exists—instead of the normal copy constructor or copy assignment operator. It is then up to the implementation of the move constructor/move assignment operator of the respective type to actually perform a move, i.e., do whatever it is that's supposed to be done for the particular type in case of initialization or assignment from an rvalue. So, in a way, what you do when you apply `std::move` is that you advertise the respective object as "this may be moved from". Whether or not it actually will be moved from (and, if so, what that actually means) is up to the implementation. In the particular case of `std::vector`, the move constructor/move assignment operator, by definition, guarantee that not only the contents of the original vector will be taken over from the original object, but also that the original object will be empty afterwards. In many other cases, it may be undefined behavior to do anything with an object that was moved from (except, maybe, destroy it; that one can be pretty much taken for granted as a type that doesn't at least allow that would be pretty much useless; typically, you will at least be able to assign a new value to an object that was moved from, but even that is not guaranteed in general). You always have to check for the particular type at hand what condition an object is guaranteed to be in after having been moved from…

Comment: Actually, the second move doesn't happen. The lambda ain't marked as mutable, which makes operator() const

Comment: @JVApen that's a very good point! I completely overlooked that. The function parameter `theirStuff` itself is also a reference to const to begin with. Well spotted, thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix my answer…